# MVC: Should "Display Color" logic be in the View or the Model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm programming a Ticket Management system with CodeIgniter and I have an MVC dilemma whether conditional coloring should go in the Model or in the View?
The view should display all tickets in a grid.
Let's say the tickets have deadline datetime. When there is less than an hour left, the ticket should be colored in Red, when there are between one and six hours left, the ticket should be colored in Yellow, and when there are more than six hours left, the ticket should be colored Green.

So, should the **view** contain logic like

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket):
if($hours_left >= 6): <span class="green">...</span>
else if($hours_left >= 1 and $hours_left < 6) <span class="yellow">...</span>
if($hours_left < 1): <span class="red">...</span>
```

or should the color be retrieved as a property from the **model**?

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket):
<span class="<?php echo $ticket->color; ?>">...</span>
```

In the first case, the view gets logic and it is not "dumb" anymore. Even worse, if this needs to be applied in multiple views, I need to repeat the code which is difficult to maintain, for example if I wanted to add a "blue" color.

In the second case, I will need to embed display logic within the model, which is also against MVC principles.

**Where should color logic be put?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Added helper code example

I would write a helper function that you can call in the view to add the correct CSS.

This way you are not messing with the model structure, for example if you have a field in the database called `ticket_expires`, you will still be able to use this value else where if required.

To make a helper function;

Create a file in */application/helpers* called *ticket_helper.php*
In this file put something like;

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Add Style to Ticket
 * 
 * @param string $expire_timestamp
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists('set_ticket_colour')) {
    function set_ticket_colour($expire_timestamp) {
        // do you logic here.

        // if you want to access your ticket model then...
        $_ci =& get_instance();
        // if model isn't autoloaded
        $_ci->load->model('ticket_model');
        $some_result = $_ci->ticket_model->some_function($some_param);
        return $some_result;
    }
}
```

Just remember to either load this helper when you need it, or autoload it.

So in you view;

```
<?php echo set_ticket_colour($ticket->expires_time); ?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to write that helper as a method of the Ticket_model ? Like for example: $ticket->get_color() ? Would that be possible in CI ?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't worry about color.  Rather go with some business meaning and determine *that* in your model (or further down if appropriate):

time < 1 : deadline-looming

time 1 - 6 : deadline-middle

time > 6 : deadline-ok

Or whatever makes sense.  Then rather use that as your class leaving you to pick colors and other styling as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Colour is in this case a view issue, most likely even further away in CSS.

On the other hand the "status" of a ticket is model info. There is a threshold in where a ticket goes from ok, to severe, to urgent. So give that data with the ticket:

```
$ticket['status']='severe';
```

or

```
$ticket['status']=$ticketStatusObject
```

Depending on whether the ticket statuses are also an object.

In the end that Model get's to the view and there you could apply logic. Make it semantic for example like:

```
<div class="ticket severe">
```

or

```
<div class="ticket" status="severe">
```

And off course in CSS you format it.

Now there is one interesting concept here which is difficult with MVC. Colour is view, that is most basically true. But it might also be of business purpose. Like a street-light going green-orange-red. In that case I would load the colours from a model (TicketStatusObject). You can still put them in CSS but generate the CSS based on the model because it influences business.

If you create another view layer, like a mobile app, it will use the same model and will show the same colour because that's important for your application and business.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the colour to display logic in the model (second approach)

This isnt really going against mvc principles.

What you are really doing is storing in the model whether the ticket has less than 6 hours or greater than 6 hours.

The second approach also keeps your templates cleaner, removing the presentation logic from the view, this makes the views easier for a graphic designer to understand.

I'm not a PHP developer (so can't provide the code) but I would have a helper class that provdied a static method which accepted a ticket object extracted the hours_left from it and returned the colour as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should always strive to make your views as concise as possible. That means removing as much PHP as you can and pushing it into your controllers, models, or even into a helper.

I suggest that you evaluate the hours left of every ticket in a helper and use a switch statement to return a space separated list of classes that should be applied to that ticket.

Then in your view, it would be as simple as:

```
<? foreach($ticket as $t): ?>
<div class="<?= $t['classes'];?>"><?= $t['name']; ?></div>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Then use CSS to mark up the classes.